# All the Images in Media Library is showing broken links

Tags: media-library, links

The problem which i am Facing is that images in media library and in the front of the website is showing broken links. The fact that is even if i upload new images from admin that is also showing broken links. Somebody told me to change the .htaccess file. so Here is my file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But i am not able to understand what is the problem in there. Please can someone help me over this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answers after spending some hours on it. Well i found that there was .htaccess file inside wpuploads folder with code.

```
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
```

I deleted it and hence all is working now.